# Elasticsearch filter and sort results using others documents

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a index with 2 types of documents :

Document **book** with fields :

- id
- title
- author
  etc ...

and some **stats** documents with fields

- book_id
- visits_date
- visits_count

where `book_id` is the "book" document `id` `visit_date` is yyyy-MM-dd and `visits_count` an integer

I want to search on **book** `title` or `author` or whatever and sort the results using the sum of `visits_count` from last 4 weeks ( using `visits_date` ) from documents "**stats**" using the `book_id` as reference

is it possible ? or do i have to change documents and maybe use nested ones ?

i tried this with no luck

```
{
  "index": "my_index",
  "body": {
    "query": {
      "bool": {
        "must": [
          {
            "match": {
              "title": "my term"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "aggs": {
      "group_by_entity_id": {
        "terms": {
          "field": "book_id",
          "size": 10
        },
        "aggs": {
          "filtered_date_range": {
            "filter": {
              "range": {
                "visits_date": {
                  "gte": "now-4w/w"
                }
              }
            },
            "aggs": {
              "total_visits": {
                "sum": {
                  "field": "visits_count"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "size": 0
  }
}
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can [sort search results](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/sort-search-results.html) with any `keyword` or `integer` field.

```
PUT /my-index-000001/_doc/1?refresh
{
   "product": "chocolate",
   "price": [20, 4]
}

POST /_search
{
   "query" : {
      "term" : { "product" : "chocolate" }
   },
   "sort" : [
      {"price" : {"order" : "asc", "mode" : "avg"}}
   ]
}
```

Comment: Read with more attention my question please , i have 2 different documents i search on fields in document A and want to sort using fields on document B

Comment: Oh, thanks for your kind warning. Is there any correlation ids between documents

Comment: Yes as i said the Stats documents "book_id" field is a reference of the Book document id

Comment: Okay, if the `id` in book document same with `book_id` in stats document, I recommend you to use enrich API to combine two document into one. The book documents and stats documents will be in different indices and one of them will be lookup index.https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/match-enrich-policy-type.html

Comment: No i don't think that's an option in my case as i have n documents Stats for 1 document Book . 
There are one document Stats per day with the total count of visits . And i need to filter using date and make sum according to the date filters

Comment: Sounds good to me. IF you have n stats documents for 1 book document, you can use the book index as lookup table. And all the stats documents will include the information about the book document.